# Python input argument

Tags: python, i2c

I'm using some existing code which specifies a hardware address used to fetch sensor data.

`ina260 = adafruit_ina260.INA260(i2c, address=0x45)`

(the 0x45 above is the address).

I'm trying to pass the address as an input argument on the command line as follows:

`python3 sensor.py 0x45`

So far, I've found I can access the argument using something like the below:

`print("\nAddress:", sys.argv[1])` This works fine. But I'm having trouble using this in my original code above where the address is specified.

I've tried the following, but getting lots of errors.

`ina260 = adafruit_ina260.INA260(i2c, address=sys.argv[1])`

Having searched for a while on this and being very new to python, I thought I'd ask here. I am sure it's a simple solution and I appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: use `int(sys.argv[1], base=16)`.

Comment: Thanks so much, it works perfectly now. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem here is that `sys.argv` is a list of *strings*, whereas you are trying to interpret those strings as integers (which you have expressed in hex notation).

So you convert them with int:

```py
int("7")
```

But since these are hex strings, you convert them as such:

```py
int("0x56", base=16)
```

For more details see the python docs on `int`.

Incidentally, it would have helped if you'd included the error (likely `ValueError` or `TypeError`).

Answer (score 0):

`0x45` is (hex) literal for number, what you access via `sys.argv[1]` is string. You need to convert it before use, replace

```
address=sys.argv[1]
```

using

```
address=int(sys.argv[1],base=0)
```

note that base 0 means determine base, thus allowing you to use also other bases supported by python literal, for example

```
print(int("0x45",base=0)==int("0b1000101",base=0))
```

output

```
True
```